# SSL_connect() api takes 5-7 seconds for its execution

Tags: c++, linux, networking, openssl

In our project(related to IP Phones) we have used this SSL_connect() API to establish tls connection between client (IP phone) and server basically we want to display an XML page on the IP phone screen, at present situation when we press the key for accessing the XML page it takes around 5-8 seconds to get displayed on the screen.
On wireshark trace it is visible that SSL_connect() API takes 5-8 seconds for its execution, could anyone suggest how to overcome this delay issue.

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: Please paste the (relevant sections of) the wireshark trace into your question.  Maybe someone can spot the anomaly.

Comment: SSL connection negotiation requires several round-trips, to exchange all pleasantries. With a high latency connection, like might be the case here, this result wouldn't surprise me.

Comment: Are you using TLS or DTLS? Wireshark details would be very useful to try and understand the delay

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It's fast for me (operating across the Internet), but you may well be right.  I've never captured a network trace to see how many round trips there are.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.